# Check if type instantiates a typeclass in GHCI

Tags: haskell, ghci

Is there a way to ask GHCi if a type instantiates a typeclass? I was fooling around with the `^^` operator and typed:

```
Prelude> :type (^^)
(^^) :: (Integral b, Fractional a) => a -> b -> a
```

Very useful. Then I wanted to know if Rational instantiates Fractional. I found Rational on Hoogle, dereferenced to Ratio and finally found:

```
Integral a => Fractional (Ratio a)
```

Was there an easier way? Something like:

```
:listypeclasses Rational
```

or

```
:listinstances Fractional
```

Comment: A quick way with `:set -XTypeApplications` is instantiating `a` to `Rational` (`>> :t (^^) @Rational`) which gives the type of `(^^) @Rational :: Integral b => Rational -> b -> Rational` — showing that `Fractional Rational` holds. To verify that this makes use of `Fractional Rational`, use `:t +v (^^) @Rational` (for info see `:?`) or try it with a type that is decidedly *not* `Fractional`, `:t (^^) @()` ("Could not deduce (`Fractional ()`) arising from a use of ‘^^’ ..")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `:info`, which can also be abbreviated `:i`. Use `:info <type>` to list instances on that type or `:info <class>` to list instances of that class.

In the case of `Rational`, since it is a type alias, `:info` will not list instances directly. However, it *will* tell you that it is a type alias, and you can follow that up by using `:info` on the type it’s aliased to:

```
ghci> :info Ratio
data Ratio a = !a :% !a     -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance Eq a => Eq (Ratio a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance Integral a => Ord (Ratio a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance Show a => Show (Ratio a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance (Integral a, Read a) => Read (Ratio a)
  -- Defined in ‘GHC.Read’
instance Integral a => Enum (Ratio a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance Integral a => Fractional (Ratio a)
  -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance Integral a => Num (Ratio a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance Integral a => Real (Ratio a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
instance Integral a => RealFrac (Ratio a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way:

```
> :set -XFlexibleContexts
> :t undefined :: (Fractional Rational) => Int

<interactive>:1:14: warning: [-Wsimplifiable-class-constraints]
    • The constraint ‘Fractional Rational’
        matches an instance declaration
      instance Integral a => Fractional (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      This makes type inference for inner bindings fragile;
        either use MonoLocalBinds, or simplify it using the instance
    • In an expression type signature: (Fractional Rational) => Int
      In the expression: undefined :: (Fractional Rational) => Int
undefined :: (Fractional Rational) => Int :: Int
```

This is only a warning, so the instance exists.

```
> :t undefined :: (Fractional Bool) => Int

<interactive>:1:1: error:
    No instance for (Fractional Bool)
      arising from an expression type signature
```

This is an error, so there is no instance.

(The `Int` above is arbitrary, you can use any other type instead.)